# Get percentage of group total in PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a few thousands patients, which are grouped by age in a pivot table (from 0-9, 10-19,...). The first group for example has 59 patients in total, of which 22 are dead.

How can I add a Calculated Field to show percentages of dead people within each group total (eg 37% for 22/59)?

In Value Field Settings there is something like "Show Value as: %" but that is percentage of all patients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a layout such as:

[image: SO20543584 example]

select a cell in the PT and in PivotTable Tools > Options > Tools - Formulas, Calculated Field... add a Name: such as `PerCent` and  for Formula: select `Age band Max` and <kbd>Insert Field</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then return to `Σ Values` and for Count of PerCent in *Value Field Settings...* and **Show values as** select `% of row`:

With some formatting the top of the PT might look something like this:

[image: SO20543584 second example]
.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out: I misconfigured my column and row labels. When I only have Age in the row label, this `% of row` is doing what I want